# What are the default bucketing used in flink histogram metric?

Tags: apache-flink, prometheus, grafana

I referred to the 'Histogram' section from [page](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/ops/metrics/). It talks about how to create a histogram but doesn't mention anything about default buckets.

Can someone help me with the exact code location where these default buckets are defined or advice about to specify buckets in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

That depends on which histogram implementation you are using. Flink includes wrappers for implementations from `com.codahale.metrics` and `org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive`.

For example:

```java
eventTimeLag = getRuntimeContext()
    .getMetricGroup()
    .histogram(
        "eventTimeLag",
        new DescriptiveStatisticsHistogram(10000));
```

That example is from https://github.com/ververica/flink-training/blob/master/troubleshooting/checkpointing/src/solution/java/com/ververica/flink/training/solutions/CheckpointingJobSolution3.java if you want to see it in context.